# Who is the best player?

Tags: battlefield-1

When finishing a game, best players appear on the **Higlights Page** but just one of them (the one in the middle), seems to be the best of all.

Is there any rule followed to appear as the best player of the game or is it just random?

Comment: I think it's based on the points you gain during the game, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah, from each class (I think) the player with most points gets selected but I'm almost sure I've seen players with less points than others being selected as **best player**